# javascript: find 2nd last appearance of string inside string?

Tags: javascript, location

I have this URL `http://www.something.com/category` and

```
top.location.href.substr(0, top.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") );
```

returns `http://www.something.com`

However if I have the URL `http://www.something.com/category/something` how can I again retrieve `http://www.something.com` by removing the 2nd last appearance of "/" …

Any idea? I know there is stuff like `top.location.origin`. I need a way to cut the last two "slashes" off!

Comment: When the next url comes along `www.something.com/category/something/things/`, then what? I believe your question is how to get the URL without paths.

Comment: `var foo = url.split('/', 3).join('/');`

Comment: are you trying to parse a generic URL, or are you going to be using the window.location object?

Comment: But I want to go backwards! I always want to remove the last two `/whatever/ever` path-parts. If the URL has `www.some.thing/one/two/three/four` I want to get rid of `/three/four`

Comment: @Matt Are you 100% sure that the path always contain at least three slashes in the pathname? `/one/two/three`, strip `/two/three`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with the `location` object, use:

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/';
// On this page, it shows: http://stackoverflow.com/
// Include pathname:
location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '/';
```

For your own solution, you can add `+1` to the second argument:

```
top.location.href.substr(0, top.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1 );
                                                              ^^ Hi Plus One!
```

Response to updated question (see OPs comments):

```
var href = top.location.href.replace(/(\/[^\/]+){2}\/?$/, '');
```

Comment: @OP - docs are your friends =). https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going backwards which can have a variable number of indexes, why not go forwards where you know there will only be 2 ahead of it?

```
var url = top.location.href;
var index1 = url.indexOf('/');
var index3 = url.indexOf('/', index1 + 2);
var final = url.substr(0, index3);
```